# StrokeThickness of Line is not working properly when we draw the line at the right end of the Grid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to set the StrokeThickness of the line is more than 1. But StrokeThickness is not applied properly in the line which is in the right side of the grid. left side line is working properly.
Code snippet

```
<Grid
        x:Name="BottomRightPanel"
        Width="500"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Background="Yellow">
        <Line
            x:Name="line"
            Stroke="Black"
            StrokeThickness="5"
            X1="0"
            X2="0"
            Y1="0"
            Y2="50" />
        <Line
            x:Name="line1"
            Stroke="Black"
            StrokeThickness="5"
            X1="500"
            X2="500"
            Y1="0"
            Y2="50">
        </Line>
    </Grid>
```

Screenshot:

[Line is cropped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zCna.png)

Comment: The stroke is drawn in the middle of the Line, i.e. the left half of the left Line and the right half of the right Line are outside the Grid's bounds. This becomes more obvious when you set `ClipToBounds="True"` on the Grid. That the right part is still cut off with `ClipToBounds="False"` seems odd. Looks like a bug.

Comment: You could obviously simply avoid this by using x values of `2.5` and `497.5`

Comment: Are these lines used for anything specific, or are they just decorations that are fixed to the sides of the grid?

Answer (score -1):

Decrease the X1 and X2 values of the right line to take the stroke thickness into consideration:

```
<Line
    x:Name="line1"
    Stroke="Black"
    StrokeThickness="5"
    X1="497.5"
    X2="497.5"
    Y1="0"
    Y2="50">
```

Or use a `Border`:

```
<Border Width="500" Background="Yellow"
        BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="5 0 5 0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock />
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Comment: @suganya: Did you try this or what happened?

Answer (score -1):

From my observation, you have provided some thickness for a line like 5, even though it has been drawn correctly due to this added thickness it plot like X position of 505.

Better you can adjust the X postion in below

```html
<Line
            x:Name="line"
            Stroke="Black"
            StrokeThickness="5"
            X1="0"
            X2="0"
            Y1="0"
            Y2="50" />
        <Line
            x:Name="line1"
            Stroke="Black"
           StrokeThickness="5"
            X1="495"
            X2="495"
            Y1="0"
            Y2="50"/>
```

Or else add like in below

```html
<Canvas>
            <Line
            x:Name="line"
            Stroke="Black"
            StrokeThickness="5"
            X1="0"
            X2="0"
            Y1="0"
            Y2="50" />
            <Line
            x:Name="line1"
            Canvas.Left="500"
            Stroke="Black"
            StrokeThickness="5"
            X1="0"
            X2="0"
            Y1="0"
            Y2="50" />
        </Canvas>
```

Keep the same line plot values and move that in left most by using Canvas.Left

[image]